# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 71

Tags: java, regex

[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF]

The above line showing illegal character range exception. Can anyone please help me.

if i use the above line in java code directly, it is not showing any error.

```
Pattern xmlInvalidChars = Pattern.compile("[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF]");
```

But if get the string from configuration xml file and use in the java code, it is showing error.

```
String chars = ConfigLoader.getInstance().getInvalidCharacters();
Pattern xmlInvalidChars = Pattern.compile(chars);
```

Comment: The problem is with `\uDC00-\uDBFF`, this range is out of order. What do you need to match with the pattern? Maybe you need to remove the hyphen to remove the faulty range? Also, you need single backslashes in the XML.

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew said, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_code_points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below line in configuration xml file.

```
 [^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\uD800\\uDC00-\\uDBFF\uDFFF]
```

that is i used the reverse case. i changed the single slash to double slash(\ to \) and double slash to single slash(\ to ). It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I'll post as an answer. inside your string you have loose backslashes `\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF`, therefore, it is treating `\u`as and escape character, however it is not. just add double backslashes as the rest of your regex.

---

Edit: Before compiling the pattern, try to substitute single slashes with double slashes.

```
chars = chars.replace("\\","\\\\");
```

Comment: it is not working...Actually I am using this Pattern to wrap up the invalid character present in the incoming xml file with CDATA. But this solution not working...

Comment: hmm, maybe it is because it is loading the literal string from the file?
you could try replacing single slashes in your xml file for double backslashes. or try replacing it inside java. editing my answer accordingly.